# Hover is not applied

Tags: html, css, sass

```css
&__img{
   height: 100%;
   transform:translate(-4rem) scale(1.4)
}
&__caption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transform: translate(-50% ,20%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
   
}
&:hover &__caption{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
&:hover &__img{

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="story">
        <figure class="story__shape">
                 <figure-caption class="story__caption">
                       mary smith
                 </figure-caption>
                <img src="img/nat-8.jpg" alt="Customer Profile" class="story__img">
        </figure>
        <div class="story__text">
            <h3 class="heading-teritiary u-margin-bottom-small">I have best weekend </h3>
            <p >Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem incidunt illo harum nam. Nesciunt dolores commodi aliquid, asperiores animi quo illum impedit itaque in optio iure, totam, illo ipsum tempore.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The hover effect is not applied. It hides the caption and the text. When I hover it is supposed to show them.
Also the scale doesn't change. I can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: your css looks like its missing a parent selector

Comment: The & can only be used in css if it is within another element. They cannot be at the top level.

Comment: there is another parent element at the top for the story class, it works when i delete the transform ppty in the image , but when i apply transform ppty in the image the caption text hides it should be visible . why it hides when i add transform ppty

Comment: Your question miss something on the sass code, like parent selector.

Comment: I tried here and it work https://jsfiddle.net/zy4ke3ra/